# Edit text out of the screen with GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textfield, android-gridlayout

I have the following layout, where the edit texts goes out of the screen with apparently no reason. I've trying to find a similar issue but I couldn't. It should be an easy one but I've tried many things without luck.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="dsgsdgsd"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@color/red" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTitle"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:inputType="text">
        </EditText>

        <View
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#E6E6E6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCategory"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Category"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editCategory"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:inputType="text" />            

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateAccount"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="createExpense"
            android:text="Done"
            android:textColor="@color/red" />
    </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your updated code:

You were missing some width, height attributes, and you had used match_parent in earlier element like View, which prevented any later element to get space on screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="dsgsdgsd"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@color/red" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTitle"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#E6E6E6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Category"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editCategory"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateAccount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="createExpense"
            android:text="Done"
            android:textColor="@color/red" />
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The output without color and background as it gives me error due to missing resource is:

[image]

Here you can see both your edittexts in screen.

Comment: great, it worked! How can I have the Done button placed in the center? Layout_gravity = center is not working as it can be seen in your picture.

Comment: @Rafag that is due to its paret is grid layout, if you just put that button out of grid layout, it will position in center :)

Answer (score 0):

try this may be this help you

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="dsgsdgsd"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/red" />

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTitle"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="text" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#E6E6E6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCategory"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Category"
        android:textColor="@color/grey" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCategory"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:inputType="text" />            

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCreateAccount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="createExpense"
        android:text="Done"
        android:textColor="@color/red" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your EditText part to This one:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="dsgsdgsd"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@color/red" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTitle"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:inputType="text">
        </EditText>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:background="#E6E6E6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Category"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editCategory"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateAccount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:onClick="createExpense"
            android:text="Done"
            android:textColor="@color/red" />
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general comment, you can never use `wrap_content` with `EditText`, it will always take the content size and not respect any other boundaries, so a user can always blow up a layout simply by typing excessive text. It took me ages to realise this very basic observation of how android prioritises various constraints.

In this context, when a GridLayout decides it cannot fit a column within its parent boundaries, it gives up and comes up with a faulty result, so typically we bound a GridLayout by screen width, the first column that exceeds the width will be forced off screen.

If you want to have large and small entry fields to match data sizes, the easiest way is to define dummy columns with weights that can be used to take up screen space, or spanned for larger fields.